# How to Search from database without HTML tags?

Tags: html, mysql, sql

My table has column its name is "text". It contain HTML text like this eg..

```
one<span style=""font-weight: normal;""><i>Subtitle</i>
```

If we take above example actually it contain `one  Subtitle`

I want to implement the search function.
My query is

```
select * from minute_item where (text like '%a%'
OR text like 'a%'
OR text like '%a'
OR text like 'a') order by meeting_minute_id desc
```

My problem is if I search "a" above record coming as a results because it contains `span` and `normal` words.

But the actual content is `one  Subtitle`

How can i do search which ignores the html tags while searching the records?

Comment: I do not really understand your Question. How exactly are you fetch from your database? PHP? Please show us some steps you have taken to do this.

Comment: actually i want to know about the query....i want to search from text column(this text column contain html text).if search part contain in the html tags i want to ignore it

Comment: Just an idea, but how about a trigger that on insert and update it writes the data to another column without the HTML tags and then search that field.